# How to create MySQL statement to insert into a table by setting values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert rows into a table using values from another table.

The following statement is approx what I want, I just can't figure out how to do the SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO forumlink
SET 
    forumlink.personid = fp.posterid, 
    forumlink.link = '/app-views/forum/post-view?postID=' + fp.postid,
    forumlink.type = 'MYPOSTS'
(SELECT posterid, postid FROM forumpost fp);
```

Thanks for helping.

BobC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler than you're making it:

```
INSERT INTO forumlink (personid, link, type)
SELECT fp.posterid, CONCAT('/app-views/forum/post-view?postID=', fp.postid), 'MYPOSTS'
FROM forumpost fp;
```

You can read more about the syntax in the relevant [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: You can't use `+` to concatenate strings in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the fixed values to the ones you are selecting from the other table and use an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) query:

```
INSERT INTO forumlink (personid, link, type)
SELECT posterid, CONCAT('/app-views/forum/post-view?postID=', postid), 'MYPOSTS'
FROM forumpost
```